# why angularJs does not showing the result on page load?

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm new in `AngularJs`. I'm trying to fetching the result from database and showing in `li` using angularjs. I'm aslo using anguarjs `filter` and its working fine. My problem is that script does not showing the result on page load.

### Php

```
// Create connection
    $pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=dummy_db;host=localhost","root","");
    $statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable");
    $statement->execute();
    $results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
    $a = '';
    foreach($results as $__){
        $a .= json_encode($__).',';

    }
```

### HTML and AngularJS

```
<body  ng-app="angapp"  ng-controller="angCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="findname"  />
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="stu in students | filter:findname">
            <img src="images/12.jpg" width="200" height="200"  />
            <span>Name :{{stu.u_name}}</span><br />
            <strong>Email :{{stu.u_mail}}</strong>
        </li>
    </ul>
<script>
    var testApp = angular.module('angapp',[]);
    testApp.controller('angCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.students=[
            <?php echo $a; ?>
        ]

    });
</script>
```

### Json Sample

```
$scope.students=[ {"u_name":"Adrian","0":"Adrian","u_mail":"Aenean.sed@ut.net"} ]
```

Above script is working fine when i put the text in `input` field the result showing properly but it does not showing the result on page load. Can anyone guide me where i'm wrong that i can fix the issue. I would like to appreciate if someone guide me. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine (angularjs side), just make sure you've referenced angularjs.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body  ng-app="angapp"  ng-controller="angCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="findname"  />
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="stu in students | filter:findname">
            <img src="images/12.jpg" width="200" height="200"  />
            <span>Name :{{stu.u_name}}</span><br />
            <strong>Email :{{stu.u_mail}}</strong>
        </li>
    </ul>
<script>
    var testApp = angular.module('angapp',[]);
    testApp.controller('angCtrl',function($scope){
       $scope.students=[ {"u_name":"Adrian","0":"Adrian","u_mail":"Aenean.sed@ut.net"} ];

    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You are telling about js file `angular.min.js` ?

Comment: Yes, as you might see the snippet above works with your code, but I couldn't test php side. If your data comes to controller then everything looks fine.

Comment: Yes my file and data properly loading i have checked

Comment: Then simulate your case including php by adding a code snippet, otherwise angularjs side the code is OK.